# Python 3, else causing syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

Hi all so i have this piece of code in python 3:

```
def spss_script_3tests (dictionary):
inv_test_dict = {v: k for k , v in dictionary.items()}
for i in excel_log_absent['Pupil\nID/Barcode ']:
    pupil_id=(i.split('-'))[2]
    test_no=(i.split('-'))[1]
    #index in spss data of pupil id
    spss_pid_index=spss_pupilid.index[spss_pupilid[('PupilID',)] == pupil_id].tolist()
    # if t1 name in spss = t1 number in excel using dictionary
    if (spss_pupilid[('T1name',)][spss_pid_index] == dictionary[test_no]).iloc[0]:
        print('if PupilID = ',"'",pupil_id,"'",' Attendlog1 = 1',sep='')
        print('if PupilID = ',"'",pupil_id,"'",' testnum1 = ',test_no,sep='')
    else:
        print('if PupilID = ',"'",pupil_id,"'",' Attendlog2 = 1',sep='')
        print('if PupilID = ',"'",pupil_id,"'",' testnum2 = ',inv_test_dict[spss_pupilid[('T2name',)][spss_pid_index[0]]],sep='')
    else:
```

alot of useless info but the last `else:`is flagging up a syntax error and i have no idea why. As far as i know everything that's indented should be, every `(` and `[` is accounted for and a print statement works fine there but a condition (else, if, while) doesn't.

Any help would be much appreicated

Comment: You can't have 2 `else:` clauses... do you have your indentation correct?

Comment: yup im an idiot..its been a long friday. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a issue with the identation or just you don't get the point of the `else`. With a simple `else` all the data that doesn't enter in your first if will enter in the else.

You can create a `else if` in python is `elif` your code should look similar to this:

```
if expression1:
   statement(s)
elif expression2:
   statement(s)
else:
   statement(s)
```